# System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' on drawing a rectangle with g.DrawRectangle()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a bill layout that is flexible with the length of the text so I am calculating the length of the text asynchronously and using its result to draw a rectangle. but when I execute the code I got an InvalidArgument exception.

here the code:

```cs
        private async void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get Graphics
            var g = e.Graphics;

            // Constants
            const int FontSize = 16;
            const int PassegerFontSize = 12;

            // Brushes
            SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

            // Pens
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(blackBrush, 2);

            // Constants
            const int MarginY = 3;

            // Fonts
            Font senderBoxFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, FontSize);
            Font passengerBoxTitleFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, PassegerFontSize, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font passengerBoxFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, PassegerFontSize);
            FontFamily algerianfamily = FontFamily.GenericSansSerif;
            try
            {
                algerianfamily = new FontFamily("Algerian");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                algerianfamily = FontFamily.GenericSansSerif;
            }
            Font algerianFont = new Font(algerianfamily, PassegerFontSize);

            // Calculating Header X
            int imgX = (e.PageBounds.Width - header.Width) / 2;
            int imgY = 15;

            // SenderInfo Box Details Calculation
            string invoiceString = $"INVOICE No :- {recordData.InvoiceID}";
            string dateString = $"Date :- {DateToSting(recordData.BillDate)}";
            SizeF invoiceStringSize = g.MeasureString(invoiceString, senderBoxFont);
            SizeF dateStringSize = g.MeasureString(dateString, senderBoxFont);
            int senderInfoY = imgY + header.Height;
            float invoiceX = e.PageBounds.Width - imgX - invoiceStringSize.Width - 10;
            float dateX = e.PageBounds.Width - imgX - dateStringSize.Width - 10;
            int senderInfoBoxHeight = (int)(5 + invoiceStringSize.Height + dateStringSize.Height);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(imgX, senderInfoY, header.Width, senderInfoBoxHeight);

            // Main Header
            g.DrawImage(header, imgX, 15, header.Width, header.Height);

            // SenderInfo Box
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
            g.DrawString($"To, {recordData.CompanyName}", senderBoxFont, blackBrush, imgX + 10, senderInfoY + 5);
            g.DrawString($"Ref :- {recordData.ReferenceName}", senderBoxFont, blackBrush, imgX + 10, senderInfoY + FontSize + 5 + 10);
            g.DrawString(invoiceString, senderBoxFont, blackBrush, invoiceX, senderInfoY + 5);
            g.DrawString(dateString, senderBoxFont, blackBrush, dateX, senderInfoY + FontSize + 5 + 10);



            string title = "Sr.\nNo";
            SizeF titleSize = g.MeasureString(title, passengerBoxTitleFont);
            int titleBoxX = imgX;
            int titleBoxY = (header.Height + senderInfoBoxHeight + imgY + MarginY);
            int titleWidth = (int)(5 + titleSize.Width + 5);
            int titleHeight = (int)(5 + titleSize.Height + 5);
            Rectangle titleRect = new Rectangle(titleBoxX, titleBoxY, titleWidth, titleHeight);
            Rectangle titleBounds = new Rectangle(titleBoxX + 5, titleBoxY + 5, titleWidth, titleHeight);
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, titleRect);
            g.DrawString(title, passengerBoxTitleFont, blackBrush, titleBounds);

            string nop = "Name tOf Passenger";
            SizeF nopSize = g.MeasureString(nop, passengerBoxTitleFont);
            var task = CalculatePassengerNameWidth(passengerBoxTitleFont);
            int nopWidth = 0;

            Trace.WriteLine(nopWidth.ToString());
            int nopBoxX = imgX + titleWidth;
            int nopBoxY = (header.Height + senderInfoBoxHeight + imgY + MarginY);
            int nopHeight = (int)(5 + titleSize.Height + 5);



            foreach (var rec in recordData.Travellers)
            {

                var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(rec.Name, passengerBoxTitleFont);
                if (nopWidth < size.Width)
                {
                    nopWidth = size.Width;
                }
            }

            int paddingX = (int)((nopWidth - nopSize.Width) / 2);
            int paddingY = (int)((nopHeight - nopSize.Height) / 2);

            Rectangle nopRect = new Rectangle(nopBoxX, nopBoxY, nopWidth, nopHeight);
            Rectangle nopBoudns = new Rectangle(nopBoxX + paddingX, nopBoxY, nopWidth, nopHeight);

            Trace.WriteLine($"{nopWidth}, {nopHeight}, {nopBoxX}, {nopBoxY}");
            Trace.WriteLine(nopRect.ToString());
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, nopRect);
            g.DrawString(nop, passengerBoxTitleFont, blackBrush, nopBoudns);


        }
```

here is the function that I am running for calculation:

```cs
        private async Task<float> CalculatePassengerNameWidth(Font font)
        {
            float maxWidth = 0;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                foreach (var rec in recordData.Travellers)
                {

                    var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(rec.Name, font);
                    if (maxWidth < size.Width)
                    {
                        maxWidth = size.Width;
                    }
                }

            });
            return maxWidth;
        }
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Have you logged the values of `nopBoxX`, `nopBoxY`, `nopWidth` and `nopHeight`? If so, what are they?

Comment: yes, nopWidth = 204, nopHeight = 49, nopBoxX = 91, nopBoxY = 253

Comment: You have weird stuff there: The paint method has been removed (post it), `imgX` (unknown) is assigned to a local variable (`int titleBoxX = imgX;`), then used somewhere else - You're awaiting a method that doesn't really belong to a paint procedure, you should calculate that measure when the data changes, not each time you *paint something* (and it's not clear what you're painting onto) -- You have `string nop = "...";`, but you measure `title` right after (`g.MeasureString(title, passengerBoxTitleFont);`). -- Don't mix `TextRenderer.MeasureText` and `Graphics.MeasureString` etc.

Comment: **You need to specify where `g` is coming from** -- When you use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` to measure a string that is being painted into a specific device context, use the overload that accepts an `IDeviceContext` argument (pass `e.Graphics` of course, the object that describes the current device context - again, the origin of the Graphics object you're using matters, add that information)

Comment: Thanks, I will change and see what happens.

Comment: thank you @Jimi, the problem was that I was calculating the values at the time of drawing which should not be done during the drawing as you said, I pre-calculated all the values and my issue got solved. what was happening was when I awaited the function CalculatePassengerNameWidth it get awaited and the control moved towards rendering and the value for nopWidth was not calculated so it was invalid and it was throwing an exception. Thanks Again.

Comment: @DarshanPanzade - please post your own solution as an answer.